# two angles are changing simultaneously accelerometer android

Tags: android, accelerometer

I wrote a code to get orientation of the device using accelerometer alone. But two angles are changing simultaneously.i mean pan,tilt or tilt roll or roll pan any two of them vary almost equally for every orientation. Why is it happening ?

```
     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

         switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
         case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
             System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mGravs, 0, 3);
         break;
              default:
                         return;
         }
         X=mGravs[0];
         Y=mGravs[1];
         Z=mGravs[2];
      if(i==1){
          R=Math.sqrt(X*X+Y*Y+Z*Z);
          pan1=Math.round((180/Math.PI)*Math.acos(X/R)) ;
          tilt1=Math.round((180/Math.PI)*Math.acos(Y/R)) ;
          roll1=Math.round((180/Math.PI)*Math.acos(Z/R));
          i=0;
      }

      else{

        R=Math.sqrt(X*X+Y*Y+Z*Z);
          pan=Math.round((180/Math.PI)*Math.acos(X/R))-pan1;
          tilt=Math.round((180/Math.PI)*Math.acos(Y/R))-tilt1;
          roll=Math.round((180/Math.PI)*Math.acos(Z/R))-roll1;
          text.setText("Angle X" +pan+"\nAngle Y" +tilt+"\nAngle Z" +roll);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TYPE_ACCELEROMETER return values that measures the device acceleration. You cannot get orientation from TYPE_ACCELEROMETER alone. You have to combine it with TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD, using these results to get the rotation matrix and then call getOrientation to get the device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Using accelerometer, you can only determine the device orientation relative to the gravity vector (pointing down). So in the (i==1) part, you calculate the angles with the gravity vector.

Why do you subtract two of angles in the 'else' part? This will give you some kind of orientation change. 
If you want to determine orientation **change**, you better use the gyroscopes (if available).

Comment: I am subtracting the initial angle from it so that i get relative angle of the device from that position.

Comment: OK, but keep in mind that if you use an accelerometer, you will only detect changes in orientation relative to the gravity vector. E.g. rotating the device in the plane perpendicular to gravity (spinning it flat on a table) will not me detected. A gyroscope can measure this easily.